# WooCommerce adding custom fields (newby)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, custom-fields

I'm a newbie when it comes to WooCommerce and PHP. I want to program a plugin that provides "Custom Fields" for WooCommerce in the backend in WordPress, among other things.
I've already tried x instructions from the web, but my backend doesn't show me any custom fields in WC. What am I doing wrong?

To test it, I did the following:
When activating my plugin I call an activation-function in my activate.php:

```
<?php

namespace STBOOKSPLGIN;

class Activation {

public static function activate() {

  
    $role = get_role( 'administrator' );

    if( ! empty( $role ) ) {
      $role->add_cap( 'stbooks_manage' );

      add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wc_add_custom_field' );

      function wc_add_custom_field() {
  
          // Print a custom text field
  
          woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
  
              'id' => '_wc_custom_field_text',
  
              'label' => 'TEST Wc Custom Text Field',
  
              'description' => 'This is a custom field, you can write anything you want here',
  
              'desc_tip' => 'true',
  
              'placeholder' => 'Custom text'
  
          ) );
  
      }
    }

}
```

}

Actually, a custom text field should now appear. But there is nothing. It doesn't matter whether it's a single product etc.
What am I doing wrong? Ich tried several other code-snippets from the Web with woocommerce_wp_text_input() etc. and the add action-hook, but nothing.

I also tried to include the code directly in myplugin.php, but the hook didn't work from there either.

As I said, I am a newbie. And I'm happy to receive any tips.
Thank you.

Kind regards
marlowe

Comment: 1. You check if there is administrator role ?
2. $role->add_cap( 'stbooks_manage' ); makes no sence 
3. what is 'wc_add_custom_field-shit' ? 
4. wc_add_custom_field() this function is not executed.

Comment: Ups, sorry. the "-shit" isnt in the original code…       add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'wc_add_custom_field' ); Ive changed it above (and I removed the $role->add_cap() in my code) Nothing changes. No Custom Field.

Comment: The function by itself works if you fix your add_action part. Is role returning something ?

Comment: Thanx Martin. Yes, role is NOT empty. But to be sure: I removed the if-statement. There is just the "add_action(xyz) and the function wc_add_custom_field() in the activate-function(). The activation  itself runs… But there is no Custom field in the backend of WooCommerce…;-(

Comment: Do you wait woocommerce to load ? I think you are trying to execute your plugin before woocommerce. Read this - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/

Comment: I have tested the funtion directly in functions.php so i guess that is the problem :)